# How I can get nodes of type basic page of current month only in drupal views

Tags: views, 7

I want to create a view which display result of current month only. If I will add post date field in filter then what operator I will choose and how i can get results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 'Filter criteria' with the next settings
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I too need to show current months node...could u pls share the steps...for me image is blocking here...

Comment: 1. In the "ADD FILTER CRITERIA" window choose "Date: Date (node)" option.
2. In the "CONFIGURE EXTRA SETTINGS FOR FILTER CRITERION DATE: DATE (NODE)" window "Date selection form element" should be "Text", "Filter granularity" should be "Month", "Date field(s)" choose "Content: Post date".
3. In the "CONFIGURE FILTER CRITERION: DATE: DATE (NODE)" window "Operator" should be "Is greater than or equal to" in the next select choose "Enter a relative date" and enter "now" in the "Relative date" field

Answer (score 0):

Create a date filter using the post or create date with a granularity of **month** and then in the relative date field, set it to be equal to **now** and that should do it.

Comment: Can you please explain more with any screen shot

Comment: Andrew has added the screenshots below.